# Where to find more documentation on Ogre3D?

Tags: ogre

I sucessfully managed to compile Ogre with MSVC2010 and I could dabble with the tutorials.

However, is there a website I am missing where there would be more ressources / infos?

The documention of the lib itself is very scarce and their wiki pages contain very few content, which is mostly outdated. For instance I'm trying to understand how the paging terrain manager works but I wasn't even able to find a single code snippet of a basic example, I don't even know which classes manage this effect.

So what's the best way to learn how to use Ogre? Are there some ressources outside of the main website?

Thanks

Comment: their forums are pretty full of answered questions on all kinds of topics

Comment: Yeah, I've been using Ogre3D for several months now and the forums have loads of relevant content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a very active community in the [forums](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/) as well as the IRC chat. You also mentioned the [wiki](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Home) yourself, which often is a good entry point.

Apart from that, some other not-yet mentioned places to look:

- [The API Reference](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/html/)
- [The Manual](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/manual/)

Plus, don't forget our growing list of samples which should provide exactly what you asked for: a condensed, basic example of a certain feature. In your case the following two should be relevant:

- Sample_Terrain
- Sample_EndlessWorld

Comment: Probably also relevant in your situation: http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=60456

Comment: thanks
I don't actually have Sample_EndlessWorld on the sample files I downloaded, how come?

Comment: That particular sample is part of Ogre 1.9 which is still in development (RC1 should be released soon). So you need to grab the source directly from [the repository on BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/sinbad/ogre/src/48dde1772c8d3395a016d1913749f9601b70b58d/Samples/EndlessWorld?at=v1-9)